# Machine learning Overfitting of model

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

Can you please help me to understand how to select max depth, estimators for my code? 
 if ml_model_type == 'Decision Tree':

```
    grid_parameters = [{'n_estimators': [30], 'max_depth': [10, 12, 15], 
                         'min_samples_split': [2,4], 'min_samples_leaf': [1]} ]

n_splits = 4
n_jobs = 4
```

Comment: this is not a correct way to address your question. in fact this is not a question at all. please do not just paste code and expect the others to figure out what is wrong. describe your issue better

Comment: @csymvoul , please have a look now .

Comment: @poorva You need to give more context. For example, what library are you using? Where do you use these parameters? I'm assuming this is xgboost or something like that, but I can't know.

Try to create a minimally working example in code, where we can exactly see what's going on.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Again you did not write your question properly. But maybe you could take a look at this article: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-number-size-decision-trees-xgboost-python/

Comment: Please check this guide on how to ask good questions in StackOverflow, for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask